# Using $set to nest value in Meteor using dot notation doesn't work

Tags: mongodb, meteor

I'm having trouble setting a nested value in a Meteor collection. I have:

```
Programs.update({ _id: progs[i]._id }, { $set: { "Year.RoommWk1": room }});
```

My console is giving the error: "MinimongoError: cannot use the part 'RoommWk1' to traverse c16"

c16 is the value of the current Year field. I want to nest the value of RoomWk1, which is '21A',  under the year field value 'c16'.

Not sure where I'm going wrong.

EDIT:

Current structure of documents is:

```
{
  "_id" : ObjectId("56ce676c082e64f956411a3c"),
  "RecordID" : 8514,
  "FullName" : "AIDAN ANDERSON",
  "Year" : "c16",
  "CampYear" : "ssipc16",
  "Week1" : "1",
  "Week2" : "2",
  "Week3" : "0",
  "Week4" : "0",
  "Week5" : "0",
  "Week6" : "",
  "Notes" : "",
  "RoomateRequest" : "Per, Ollie, Paul B., Linus, Sam L.",
  "LessonRequest" : "",
  "ArrivalInfo" : "",
  "Automobile" : 0,
  "Repertoire" : "Bach"
}
```

The nesting doesn't exist at the moment, but I need to nest the 'RoomWk1' to 'RoomWk5' fields under a specific year moving forward.

Comment: pls show your query document and model design

Answer (score 0):

I would put the current year selector outside the mongo. From my experience mongo doest like [i]
`var currentYear = progs[i]._id`

My guess is you have multiple years and you have the following nest.

`{year:
   {c16: {
      RoomWk1: room
   }}
}`

You can use a second selector to get more control. I'm not sure you have this in the document but if there is a 'year' equivalent I would add that to the selector. That way you can use the $ in your $set

`var currentYear = progs[i]._id
Programs.update({_id: currentYear, 'year': 'c16'}, {$set: {'year.$.RoomWk1': room}}}`

Comment: Interesting, I've never had issues with iterating within Mongo.